# An Inclusion-Strict Notion of Homotopy

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples, homotopy-theory

I was thinking about another problem, and at one point it would have been convenient to be able to say this:

> Let $A$ be closed in the metric space $X$, and $F: A \times I \rightarrow X$ a deformation of $A$ to the point $a$.  There is a deformation $F': A \times I \rightarrow X$ deforming
> $A$ to $a$ such that if $s < t$ and $f_s(x) = f_s(y)$ then $f_t(x) = f_t(y)$.

In other words, if the homotopy identifies two points $x, y \in X$, then those points stay identified for the rest of the homotopy.  Here it's assumed that $A$ is contractible and $F$ is a homotopy equivalence.  For general homotopies between closed subsets it's false; for example, the reverse homotopy of a contraction from a non-degenerate set.  I don't know if "closed" is required; the same question could be asked for open sets, or for spaces more general than metric.

Another type of counterexample for general subsets would be identifying the center point of two closed discs, and homotoping one boundary circle to the other.  It's actually a bit more complicated to prove than you might expect, but you can't get an "inclusion-strict" homotopy equivalence.

But counterexamples seem kind of hard to come up with, generally.  Has this concept been studied before?

Comment: I have seen these called sticky homotopies. They are used in a very restricted setting of homotopies of discrete sets of n points in the work of Weiss and Boavida. I am also reminded of the notion of “controlled topology” which studies homotopies with some type of restriction. Quinn is one of the biggest names there.

Comment: Maybe worth pointing out: isotopies have this strictness property (e.g. the two boundary circles in your example are homotopic but not isotopic).

Comment: There were counterexamples in that post on overflow I linked you to a couple of days ago. I can actually give a postive answer in a very special case: if $X$ is an ANR, then any open cover $\mathcal{U}$ has a refinement $\mathcal{V}$ such that any two $\mathcal{V}$-close maps are homotopic by a homotopy relative the coincidence set.

Comment: Are you referring to the thread with those two counterexamples?  To be honest those counterexamples used a lot of geometric machinery that I'm not familiar with, I couldn't quite follow them yet but I'm boning up on this stuff rn.  I'll come back to them!  Btw, I am using Sakai's book, is it an OK one or not serious enough?  I have Hu and Borsuk as well, but they're so old I'm worried to try to learn from a potentially outdated source, where the proofs are still fresh and hard AF

Comment: Sakai's book is fantastic. I have learned a lot from reading it (he has two now, and both are great). Borsuk's book is difficult just for its age. Hu's book is very readable but quite short.